# power series of derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, power-series

when $x>-1$ , $f(x)=x\log (x+1)$, and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ 
1. find $f'(x)$ & $f''(x)$

$f'(x) = \log (x+1) + \frac{x}{x+1}$ 
$f''(x)=\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

  2. show that $f'''(x)=g'(x)-g''(x)$ 
$g'(x)= \frac{-1}{(x+1)^2}$ 
$g''(x)= \frac{2}{(x+1)^3}$
$f'''(x)= \frac{-1}{(x+1)^2}+ \frac{-2}{(x+1)^3}$
hence it is proved that $f'''(x)=g'(x)-g"(x)$

3. n is integer, find$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}f^{(k)}(0)$
   i tried to find the pattern but could not find it. is there any relation of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?
   is there any relation with maclaurin too?
   $f'(0)=0$ 
   $f'(0)=2$
   $f'(0)=-3$
   $f'(0)=8$
   $f'(0)=30$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f'''(x)=g'(x)-g''(x)$, then it is easy to see that for $k\ge 3$ we have

$$f^{(k)}(x)=g^{(k-2)}(x)-g^{(k-1)}(x)$$

In addition, it is easy to see that

$$g^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k k!\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k+1}}$$

and hence $g^{(k)}(0)=(-1)^kk!$.

Finally, we have for $n\ge1$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}f^{(k)}(0)&=f'(0)+f''(0)+\sum_{k=3}^{2n+1}f^{(k)}(0)\\\\
&=0+2+\sum_{k=3}^{2n+1}\left(g^{(k-2)}(0)-g^{(k-1)}(0)\right)\\\\
&=2+\underbrace{\sum_{k=3}^{2n+1}\left((-1)^{k-2}(k-2)!-(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)! \right)}_{\text{A Telescoping Sum}}\\\\
&=1-(2n)!
\end{align}$$

Comment: thankyou so much!! but how did you get $1-(2n)!$? $\sum_{k=3}^{2n+1}((-1)^{1}(1)!-(-1)^{2}(2)!+(-1)^{2}(2)!-(-1)^{3}(3)!$ , inside will cancel out so left with $=f'(0)+f''(0)+(-1)+ (-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!(0) $ is this correct? and also what is the relation between n and k? why the last value is 2n+1?

Comment: we will be left with $0+2+ -1- (-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!$ ?

Comment: When $k=2n+1$, $(k-1)!=(2n)!$.

Comment: thankyou so much!!, so k and n has no relation right? and the role of n here, it only means that the last term is $2n+1$? and also is it possible to find $f'''(X)$ by differentiate it and not using $g(x)$? but i guess if only use f we cant find pattern(?)

Comment: Happy New Year.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that $k$ is a "dummy" summation index; $n$ is a fixed integer.  One can find $f'''$ without appealing to the function $g$.  But, using $g$ evidently facilitates analysis.

Comment: When you have enough reputation points, feel free to up vote as you see fit.  ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Do you know (or can you compute) the Maclaurin series for $g(x)$? If so, then (differentiating the result from part 2) $f^{(n)}(x) = g^{(n-2)}(x)-g^{(n-1)}(x)$ and the right-hand side can be computed from the Maclaurin series.

Comment: thankyou so much!!